# Read config file in python without any section

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to read a config file in python. My file contents look like this

```
name:age:location
abc:1:US
pqr:2:UK
```

I tried to use the config parser to read the data. Since the file does not contain any section, I added it on the fly

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
with open("foo.conf") as stream:
    parser.read_string("[top]\n" + stream.read())
```

I am not sure how can I iterate the whole file data and read.

Comment: All on one line? Thatvs the format of the config file?

Comment: Yes all in one line

Comment: As pointed above, configparser, we'll have a tough time (emphasis on `delimiters, default value: ('=', ':')`. Would suggest treating the file as a regular (text) let's say and parse its content.